# Do we know of pagan creation myths that had a creation week?

Tags: religion, religious-history

Is the creation week an introduction by Abrahamic religions, or are there other known religions that also have, as part of their creation myths, a creation week (not necessarily of 7 days)?
I've googled this question but only got results discussing the creation week in Genesis.

Comment: The preliminary research I did was googling this question but only getting results discussing the creation week in Genesis.

Comment: My quick search supports yours. I can't call to memory an example, and most of the examples I can find of pagan creation myths (they are not universal; some pagan traditions don't have a creation myth) tend towards longer durations.  Interesting. i wonder if anyone can cite a counterexample?

Comment: (from memory, unreliable), I think that some Native American tribes have a creation mythology that features 7, although not in a week - but neither is it locked into narrative time. Might be worth exploring.

Comment: Since this question hinges on a knowledge of Mythology, rather than History, it might have been better asked on the [Mythology stack](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @justCal thanks for the hint, I'll go there if the bounty is not enough to attract answers.

Comment: @MCW no of course not, the term pagan was only used to mean "non-abrahamic" and I am fine with removing it. Also, if it can be migrated with the bounty then yes, please do it.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a "week"? That's a culturally-bound method of time keeping. I think the 7-day week is specifically a Jewish (with a Bablyonian antecedent) thing, so you're not going to find it beyond this ANE.

Comment: @cmw Any length of week is fine. I would define "creation week" for the purpose of this question as "specified duration, relatively short, significant for the calendar". I'm looking for similarities between religions, and this one strikes me as one area that doesn't seem like it should be anything special, but where it seems hard to find parallel examples. The closer to a creation week of 7 days, the better, but a 10-day week, or a month, or a year, something of significance, is still better than no answer.

Comment: @MCW - Actually, it can't. I just tried. Its too old.

Comment: @T.E.D. So I have to create a new question on the other site?

Comment: @kutschkem - It looks that way, yes. Sorry.